# Rendering error with Android APK on Blackberry Z10

Tags: apk, blackberry-10

Hi we have an Android app with an Viewpager
The pages contain Webviews.

Sometimes a page is broken as you can see in the bottom in the attached screenshot.

This seems to be a refreshing error, since when i go 2 pages head and then back again the page is ok.

Is there anything we can do about that?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the Hardware Accelleration in android.manifest solved this Problem